# Minecraft bukkit coding error, constructor... is not applicable

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

```
final TFM_Admin superadmin = new TFM_Admin(
    constructor TFM_Admin.TFM_Admin(UUID,ConfigurationSection) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor TFM_Admin.TFM_Admin(UUID,String,Date,String,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

This is the error that shows up when I try this below; I'm not sure what this means. I'm working on a plugin for Minecraft using NetBeans.

```
final TFM_Admin superadmin = new TFM_Admin(
            uuid,
            player.getName(),
            new Date(),
            "",
            false,
            false,
            true);
    superadmin.addIp(ip);
```

This boolean statement in TFM_Admin is `public TFM_Admin(UUID uuid, String lastLoginName, Date lastLogin, String loginMessage, boolean isSeniorAdmin, boolean isTelnetAdmin, boolean isBestMcPlayers, boolean isActivated)`

Comment: That's a pretty nasty constructor, I'd create a builder. The problem is that you're giving it 3 booleans, not 4.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing one boolean when you create the instance. Make sure the args in the `TFM_Admin` class and the `new` statement match up.

Answer (score -2):

You're missing a boolean (`isActivated`).